# Bootstrap Popover with textarea resetting text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue where hiding a bootstrap popover just resets the text content of my textarea within the popover. There are many of these in my page and they are created dynamically in a loop (with `int i` being the counter). Here is my html:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-title="FOR EVALUATOR'S ATTENTION" type="button" data-html="true" @*id="commentPopOver-@i"*@ @*onclick="getAttention(@i)"*@>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</button>
<div class="popoverContent" style="display: none !important">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="values[@i].AttentionComment" id="comment-@i" hidden />
        <textarea class="form-control" onchange="updateText(@i)" id="commentText-@i" rows="3">someText</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $('.popoverContent').html();
        }
    });
})
```

Now I understand that it's just recreating the popover with it's default text on load, but it should at least be keeping the changes and the value of the textarea after it is closed/hidden. I wrote this JS to try and make it populate a separate hidden input to contain the value even after reset but it didn't work:

```
function updateText(id) {
    var newtext = $('#commentText-' + id).val();
    $('#comment-' + id).val(newtext);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Razor C# variable i inside the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use  `content: function () {return $('.popoverContent').html();}` the set the content of your tooltips, the tooltips content a copy of the HTML code return by `$('.popoverContent').html();` The textarea is also a copy and not reference to the original textarea in your DOM.

When a tooltips opens the plugin inserts its HTML (including the copy mentioned above) in the DOM with a random unique ID. The plugin also insert a `aria-describedby` attribute to the elements that trigger the tooltip (the button in your case). The `aria-describedby` holds the same unique ID set for the tooltip.

Now you can use the 'hide.bs.popover` event. When the tooltips close you should copy the content of the textarea inside your tooltip to the (hidden) textarea in your DOM

## Example

### HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="po1" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-html="true">
  Popover on right
</button>

<div class="popoverContent" style="display: none !important">
    <div class="form-group">

        <textarea class="form-control"  rows="3">someText 1</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" id="po2" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-html="true">
  Popover on right
</button>

<div class="popoverContent" style="display: none !important">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control"  rows="3">someText 2</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

### javascript:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").each(function( index ) {

var that = $(this);
        $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
              return $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' + .popoverContent').html();
        } 
        });    
});



$('[data-toggle=popover]').on('hide.bs.popover', function () {
     $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' + .popoverContent textarea').html( $('#' + $(this).attr('aria-describedby') + ' .popover-content textarea').val());
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/DvOYV12bHg

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! I'm struggling to get it working though. I get a 'undefined is not a function' error unless I wrap the .each function in $(function () { <code> }) and even after that I still have the same issue. Have made a jsfiddle of my own html, and it works there, which is strange.

Comment: Oh this is embarrassing, I was still on Bootstrap 3.2.0... just update to 3.3.1. and now it works... lol